# Carry operations when adding two numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, elementary-proofs

Let $x$ be a large positive real number and let $q\leq 2$ be a positive integer. It is known that for a positive integer $n,$ there exists a unique sequence $\left\{0\leq n_k\leq q-1\right\}_{k\geq 0}$ such that $$n=\sum_{k\geq 0} n_k q^k.$$ Define the sum of digits of $n$ in basis $q$ by $$S_q(n):=\sum_{k\geq 0} n_k.$$ Is there **an asymptotic formula** for the following sum 
$$\sum_{a+b\leq x} \sigma_q(a,b),$$
where $\sigma_q(a,b)$ is the number of **carry** operations needed when adding $a$ and $b$ in basis $q.$

Many thanks.

Comment: Khadija, why do you define $S_q(n)$ if you don't use it in the rest of the question? Or am I missing something?